# How to read and write to an external file in node js

Tags: node.js, express

My logd file

```
    var winston = require('winston');
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });
var config = {'status':1};
```

my js file,

```
 log = require('../../../config/logs.js');
 exports.getcategories = function (req, res) {

   i want to write a if condition to check status in my log file
   if(log.config.status == 1)
     console.log(log)
  Categories.find(item, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err');
    }
    data = { status: 'fail', error_code: 1, result: [] };
    if (result) {
      data = { status: 'success', error_code: 0, result: result };
    }
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```

I am not sure about the process i followed,cn any one help me out please.........

Comment: Check the native `fs` api https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

please read this doc. it support read / write file.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html